# Is there a method to fix this error? => (Something went wrong TypeError: res.json is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

When I fetch a object to add to my mongodb

```
const response = await fetch("/api/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

I get [Something went wrong TypeError: res.json is not a function] here

```
import React from "react";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import wordModel from "../../../models/wordModel";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
  try{
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI)
    console.log("It's good");
    const word = await wordModel.create(req.body);
    res.json({ word }); 
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    return new Response;
  }
}
```

and then in my db appear a document that contain random numbers and letters

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question and select as resolved. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json

Shouldn't you something like this?

```
export async function POST(req, res) {
  const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
  try{
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI)
    console.log("It's good");
    const word = await wordModel.create(req.body);
    return NextResponse.json({ someProp: word }, { status: 200 })
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Something went wrong" }, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```